# Is there fertilizer management web site available?

Tags: fertilizer

Does anyone know if a fertilizer management web site is available?

I'm looking for a site where I can enter my plant/tree collection and the fertilizer that I use on each and let it know when I last fertilized the plant and then I receive an email when I should next apply fertilizer etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there is currently no such thing available. It should be possible to set up your own system on your internet device (Iphone, pad, whatever) and have that 'remind' you when its necessary, I'd have thought, but it may take some time to set it up in the way you want.

Comment: Do you know if there's a plant/fertilizer database that's available via API that I could hook a product like this into if I created one?

Comment: I've no idea what API is, first off, and any complete fertilizer database is likely to be held only by authorities - the ones who approve products for use. Also possibly for farmers or perhaps corporate professional growers to access, but I don't know any more than that. For amateurs, there's nothing available I know of.